# How do I pass multiple generic arguments that conforms to a single protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

I have a method that performs a network request based on the generic codable model thats been passed. My requirement is (for a post request), when the returning response has a different structure than the body parameters, how to modify the bellow function that could take two different codable classes. Partially completed code as bellow.

```
performWebServiceRequest <T: Codable K:Codable>(type: T.Type, 
                                      with url: URL, 
                                      requestType: String, 
                                      bodyparamData: T? = nil, // 1st instance
                                      requestOptions: [String: String]?,
                                      responseStructure: String, 
                                      successBlock: @escaping SuccessBlock, 
                                      failureBlock: @escaping FailureBlock,
                                      return_response:K.Type? = nil) { //2nd instance


}
```

As you see this code is very ugly. Is there a better way to manage this rather than maintaining two different generics (T and K) that conforms to the same protocol ?

Comment: there is 2 way to use it one with `Alamofire` & second crating a global service class as you tried but their i don't think you need to use generic class values.

Comment: You required to maintaining both generics type:```func performWebServiceRequest <T: Codable, K: Codable> (type: T.Type,
                                                     with url: URL,
                                                     requestType: String,
                                                     bodyparamData: K? = nil,
                                                     requestOptions: [String: String]?,
                                                     responseStructure: String,
                                                     completion: ((T?) -> Void)) {```

Comment: @RajaKishan what im asking is a way to handle this without maintaining two different generics, with a single protocol

Comment: @danu I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If `T` and `K` can be different from each other, you have to have different generic names for them.  There is an exception for the narrow case where the protocol they conform to doesn't have `Self` or `associatedtype` constraints, in which case you can just use the protocol itself as the type.  In that case, the function doesn't need generic syntax at all.  But that won't work for `Codable`.

Comment: yeah i need it for codable sir

Comment: I think you'll need to use another approach to make the API cleaner.   One option is the "parameter pack" idiom... you make a `struct` that you put the parameters into, and then pass that struct to the function.  That's an old idiom and is often used in complex C API's.   I prefer the "builder pattern".  You provide an API that allows you build `WebRequest` to use your example one call at a time.  Each call returns the `WebRequest` builder object so you continue in a fluid-style, and then finally you call `perform()` on it to actually do the web request.

Comment: SwiftUI is completely built using the builder pattern, in that case using the result builder feature of Swift.    You could do that too, in which case you get a very nice syntax that looks like it's built into the language, but my experience is that you can get 90% of the benefit of result builders for about 30% of the work to implement it by using the classic builder pattern.   The other 10% might be worth 70% more work if it's an API that will be widely distributed, but if it's just you, result builders aren't worth the effort.